# Resizing images to fit a square using CSS

Tags: css

I have a collection of images which I am resizing to a set width, and allowing the height to be set automatically. All images are either square, or wider than they are tall and what I would like is to have a "letterbox/widescreen" effect for the non-square images. Is there a way to have the image centred vertically inside a square border using CSS?

Edited to add a very rough and ready layout. I'd also like the images to wrap, so that if the screen is zoomed in there may be only two on a row.

[image]

Comment: How about setting it as the background image of an element?

Comment: You mean something like: http://jsbin.com/xibug/1/edit ?

Comment: can u provide the template or screenshot of what u want to acheive. i couldnt understand how u want the arrangement to be with multiple images in the container div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the actual images, meaning you have them yourself, the best solution IMO would be to crop them to be perfectly square. So if those images were 100px X 100px, you could add some `padding:10px` to give it some spacing between the edges and then your CSS border, for example:

```
div .image {
    background-image: url("images/blah.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I think that would accomplish exactly what you're wanting. :)

*NOTE: If you don't have the images yourself, I would use the CSS properties: `max-height` or `max-width`. This will keep the images proportional at least. Don't use both, just one or the other.*

Answer (score 2):

try `vertical-align:middle;` on all the images.

Comment: *"then try vertical-align:middle; on the div that includes all the images."* Why not `vertical-align:middle;` on the images?

Comment: because he has many images so I figured the whole div would be better

Comment: Can you show please how a `DIV` with CSS `vertical-align: middle;` affects the inner images?

Comment: ok you are right you can't. It works on divs not on images like I though. But it will work on the images themselves yes.

Comment: Well, than you might edit your answer to add some more info perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

u can use `background-image` instead of `<img>` inside the container `<div>` and set the CSS as

```
background:url("img_url") no-repeat ;
background-size:100% auto;
background-position:center center;
background-color:black;
```

This would give a widescreen effect for landscape images

Hope this helps!

Comment: *"`I have a collection of images`"*

Comment: btw. You can put it all into a one-liner.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan can u provide the template or screenshot of what u want to acheive. i couldnt understand how u want the arrangement to be with multiple images in the container div

Comment: Sorry I can't provide it

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the solution you have provided ie. http://jsbin.com/xibug/1/edit is the answer?
ok now i get it its vertical alignment of thumbnails. That was a very simple solution. Thanks

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan but one can apply background-image to individual thumbnail right. One has to place the image in a square-thumb-container div anyways. by giving <img> and vertical-align:middle would be an extra tag and styling. I guess background-image to square-thumb-container is more efficient. What are your thoughts on this?